# Multiple SignalR-connections/endpoints inside a single WebApp?

Tags: signalr-2

[image: An SPA depending on three separate SignalR Endpoints]

Suppose we're building an SPA (Single Page Application) which depends on a couple of independent back-end systems. Basically a *Microservices-esque* implementation of SignalR-hubs.

- Each of these back-end systems expose a **separate SignalR endpoint with a separate set of hubs**;
- The separation of these hubs across different back-end systems is intentional in design and **cannot be unified into a single one**;
- Basically, **a single browser session to the app will have to maintain a separate SignalR-connection for each endpoint** on which we depend.

From what we have gathered, this approach will not scale due to the fact - at this time of writing - most browsers seem to implement an arbitrary limit of concurrent websocket connections.

This leads us to the following questions:

- Are we correct in our assumption that **this will not scale in the browser?**
- If our assumption is correct, what are our options? **Will we need to implement a single encompassing SignalR-endpoint?**